# Differential equation and limit as an equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, steady-state

I'm trying to understand the following theorem:

Theorem: Suppose that $x=x(t)$ is a solution of $\dot{x}=F(x)$ where $F$ is continuous. Suppose that $x(t)$ approaches a finite limit $\textbf{a}$ as $t \to \infty$. Then $\textbf{a}$ must be an equilibrium state for the equation, that is, $F(\textbf{a})=0$.

I found the following proof in the Sydsaeter and Hammond (last ed.) book:
[image]
but to me is not so intuitive. Can you explain it more easily and intuitively?

Comment: Intuitively, if $|F(x)|>0$ then the projectile can't stay at that position since that implies non-zero speed, i.e. it is moving away from that point at a non-zero rate. You need speed to be zero to be stationary. On a related note, a stationary point can be stable or unstable. It's stable if $F(x)<0$ for $x$ just above the stable point and positive just below, vice versa and its unstable. Stability means the mechanism resists perturbations away from equilibrium.